# Reading a spectrum analyser in MATLAB

Tags: frequency, simulink, demodulation

When demodulating an AM waveform why is there a frequency spike on the spectrum analyser of exactly two times the carrier frequency with an upper and lower sideband. It is past the cut off frequency for the demodulator so does not affect the output waveform but I am just curious as to why this occurs

Comment: Please add a block diagram or code

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is possibly a "second-harmonic generation", sometimes known as "frequency doubling". There could be a lot of reasons why this occurs but it's difficult to narrow it down with the small amount of information that you have provided but it typically happens during rectification in your demodulation process. For instance, if you have an envelope detector, the diode would block half of the signal. There could also be a some low-pass filtering that removes high frequency activity as well. It really just depends on your demodulation design.

Comment: I have used an envelope detection demodulator with a 4 order Butterworth demodulator